# How to determine what should be the scope of the classes - Singleton or Scoped

Tags: oop, design-patterns, thread-safety, singleton

```
MetricsUtility : IMetricsUtility
{
       var context;

       MetricsUtility (ServiceProvider, Context)
       {
                 Context = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(Context);
       }
       
       function Write()
       {
                Console.Write($"The context is {Context}");
       }
}
```

vs

```
HardwareUtility : IHardwareUtility
{
          HardwareUtility()
          {
          }
          function Write(Context)
          {
                Console.Write($"The context is {Context}");
          }
}
```

What should be the scope of MetricsUtility and Hardware utility - Singleton or scoped, given Context is different for each thread.
Which factors to consider when determining the scope of the classes.

What my understanding is that
If MetricsUtility is declared Singleton it will act as a global variable and since there is Context  in the Constructor so this will lead to inconsistent behaviour when 2 or more threads access it simultaneously.
But in Hardware utility the Context is given as a function parameter so if HardwareUtility is declared as Singleton, still each thread will be passing its own Context and this will not lead to any inconsistency even it multiple threads call HardwareUtility.Write simultaneously.

Is this understanding correct. Also let me know if other than the scope of variables, (Context) in this case, there are any other factors or patterns to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is generally correct.

However, an important consideration that your first example might be missing is [pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value](https://www.google.com/search?q=pass%20by%20reference%20vs%20pass%20by%20value). Assuming it's pseudocode, the syntax doesn't suggest either. If you pass by **value** into the constructor then any change to `Context` made by one `MetricsUtility` will not be reflected in any other. Instead, the change is made to that instance of `MetricsUtility`. Conversely in your second example, if `Write` were to modify the `Context`, you must decide whether you want to modify it for just that instance of `HardwareUtility` or all of them by deciding pass-by-**reference** or pass-by-**value**.

As for which approach is correct - **there isn't one**. I can't make assumptions about your code beyond your example. However, I do have the opinion that you should minimize shared mutable state. This is especially true for multithreading. You want to be able to reason about race conditions.

The second example does a better job of minimizing shared mutable state by not giving access to the context unnecessarily and being more referentially transparent. Making the context an attribute gives you more room for error because now all the methods can access (thus mutate) it. A more philosophical discussion would foray into the motives of [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), so I'll leave it there.